# Email address regex causes syntax error in UI5

Tags: regex, xml, sapui5

My email regex (`^\w+[\w-+\.]*\@\w+([-\.]\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/`) in XML view is not working whereas numeric regex (`^[0-9]*$`) works fine.

Could you please help me if I am doing anything wrong?

```xml
<Column>
  <m:Label text="Email ID"/>
  <template>
  <m:Input id="idEmailTabEmailId"
    valueLiveUpdate="true"
    value="{
      path: 'thatEmailAddress',
      mode: 'TwoWay',
      type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String',
      constraints: {
        minLength: 1,
        maxLength: 50,
        search: '^\w+[\w-+\.]*\@\w+([-\.]\w+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'
      }
    }" />
  </template>
</Column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `search` property has a string value instead of a `RegExp` object, you have to escape the escape character. I.e. `\\` instead of a single `\`:

```regex
^\\w+[\\w-+\\.]*\\@\\w+([-\\.]\\w+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

<sup>**Note:** the above regex is **not** covering all cases of RFC 5322. See https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/</sup>

Additionally, if the regex is defined within an XML document (e.g. XMLView),  keep in mind to escape those special characters as well:

```js
&quot; // "
&apos; // '
&lt;   // <
&gt;   // >
&amp;  // &
```